# Clear Google CSE input on submit

Tags: jquery, css, google-custom-search

I have a new google CSE script that I would like to have starter text in the search input "Search Events", using CSS rather then text.

http://www.newschool.edu/localist/index-cb.html

Right now if the user types in their search term and hits enter the focus remains on the input and the Google CSE overlay works as required,

but

if a user clicks on the submit (mag glass) the starter text returns combined with the search term.

Its a small thing, but I would like to have them both work like it does with the user hits enter.

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I reread your question and you want something like this...

```
$('SUBMIT Button SELECTOR').click(function(){
           $('CSE SEARCH BAR SELECTOR').attr('value', '');
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.gsc-search-button').click(function(){
  $('.gsc-input').attr('value', '');
 });
});

Something like this? Sorry. this is new to me. if so its not working?

Comment: I don't see this jQuery in the page you posted... but ya maybe you have the wrong selectors... try $(document).ready(function() { $('input.gsc-search-button').click(function(){ $('#gsc-i-id1').attr('value', ''); }); });

Comment: Also not sure what you want to be in the bar when you hit enter, but whatever you want would be in this code $('#gsc-i-id1').attr('value', '');  

Right now it should empty the textbox, but if you wanted text just add it to ''.